# How to get Coursera API Docs ?

Tags: httprequest, coursera-api

Hi I want to use Coursera API for a tech blog purpose, like retrieving list of courses (course details, course duration , etc...) I try in coursera website to enroll for their developer program  : 
https://building.coursera.org/developer-program/

but so far I didn't get any response from them (apply sent 2 weeks ago).
I found some http request like categories :
 https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/categories

or courses : 
https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses

Where Can I find some docs with all the API Functions? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you found out any sandbox environment or docs to get more information? Basically looking forward to know how long it takes to implement COURSERA affiliation in a website and is it as simple as implementing API using javascript?

Comment: Back in time I sent a request to access their catalog. Then they were giving access to  Catalog APIs (link in my question) but it seems to be deprecated. Did you try to talk with their support / affiliation program?

Comment: There seems to be no way to contact for general/development related enquiry. I guess their API portal is available once we register as an affiliate which though is free needs information like SIN no. and all which I dont have....

Comment: It looks like some documentation is here- but their https certificate is bad: https://build.coursera.org/app-platform/catalog

Answer (score 6):

According to the link in the accepted answer, the catalog API has been deprecated. Looks like now the only way to query the catalog is through the affiliate program.

[image]